# Blank main activity due to recyclerview with a cursorloader

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-cursorloader

Right now I am trying to use recyclerview with a cursorloader. I included the cursorloader within my recyclerview adapter based on my research. I do not have the desire to put my SQLite database data into an arraylist. Right now it looks like my code is correct but when I load the app I get a blank screen. Can anyone help me see my mistake in my code?

Here is my adapter:

```
public class PrescriptionRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PrescriptionRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private CursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;
private Context mContext;
private ViewHolder holder;
Cursor prescriptionCursor;




public PrescriptionRecyclerAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    mContext = context;
    prescriptionCursor = c;
    mCursorAdapter = new CursorAdapter(mContext, c, 0) {




        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            // Inflate the view here

                    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.recycle_item, parent, false);
                return v;

        }




        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {



            // Extract data from the current store row and column
            int nameColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PrescriptionContract.PrescriptionEntry.COLUMN_PRESCRIPTION_NAME);
            int amountColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PrescriptionContract.PrescriptionEntry.COLUMN_PRESCRIPTION_AMOUNT);
            int durationColumnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PrescriptionContract.PrescriptionEntry.COLUMN_PRESCRIPTION_FREQUENCY_DURATION);
            final int columnIdIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PrescriptionContract.PrescriptionEntry._ID);

            //Read the store attritubes from the Cursor for the current stores
            String name = cursor.getString(nameColumnIndex);
            String amount = cursor.getString(amountColumnIndex);
            String duration = cursor.getString(durationColumnIndex);
            String col = cursor.getString(columnIdIndex);

            // Populate fields with extracted properties
            holder.prescriptionName.setText(name);
            holder.prescriptionAmount.setText(amount);
            holder.prescriptionDays.setText(duration);


        }
    };



}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView prescriptionName;
    public TextView prescriptionAmount;
    public TextView prescriptionDays;
    final public Button prescriptionButton;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        // Find fields to populate in inflated template
        prescriptionName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        prescriptionAmount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.amountlist);
        prescriptionDays = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.daysList);
        prescriptionButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.scheduleButton);

    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCursorAdapter.getCount();
}

public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    if (prescriptionCursor == cursor) {
        return null;
    }
    Cursor oldCursor = prescriptionCursor;
    this.prescriptionCursor = cursor;
    if (cursor != null) {
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    return oldCursor;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // Passing the binding operation to cursor loader
    mCursorAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position);
    mCursorAdapter.bindView(holder.itemView, mContext, mCursorAdapter.getCursor());
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // Passing the inflater job to the cursor-adapter
    View v = mCursorAdapter.newView(mContext, mCursorAdapter.getCursor(), parent);
    holder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return holder;
}
}
```

Here is my display activity.

```
 public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
private static final int PRESCRIPTION_LOADER = 0;
PrescriptionRecyclerAdapter mCursorAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DisplayActivity.this, EditorActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    RecyclerView prescriptionRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    prescriptionRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


    mCursorAdapter = new PrescriptionRecyclerAdapter(this, null);
    prescriptionRecyclerView.setAdapter(mCursorAdapter);


    //Kick off the loader
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(PRESCRIPTION_LOADER,null,this);

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_display, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // User clicked on a menu option in the app bar overflow menu
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to a click on the "Delete all entries" menu option
        case R.id.action_delete_all_entries:
            deleteAllPrescriptions();
            return true;

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Helper method to delete all items in the database.
 */
private void deleteAllPrescriptions() {
    int rowsDeleted = getContentResolver().delete(PrescriptionEntry.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
    Log.v("CatalogActivity", rowsDeleted + " rows deleted from prescription database");
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    // Since the editor shows all store attributes, define a projection that contains
    // all columns from the store table
    String[] projection = {
            PrescriptionEntry._ID,
            PrescriptionEntry.COLUMN_PRESCRIPTION_NAME,
            PrescriptionEntry.COLUMN_PRESCRIPTION_AMOUNT,
            PrescriptionEntry.COLUMN_PRESCRIPTION_FREQUENCY_HOURS,
            PrescriptionEntry.COLUMN_PRESCRIPTION_FREQUENCY_TIMES,
            PrescriptionEntry.COLUMN_PRESCRIPTION_FREQUENCY_DURATION,
            PrescriptionEntry.COLUMN_PRESCRIPTION_REFILL,
            PrescriptionEntry.COLUMN_PRESCRIPTION_EXPIRATION,
            PrescriptionEntry.COLUMN_PRESCRIPTION_PHARMACIST_NAME,
            PrescriptionEntry.COLUMN_PRESCRIPTION_PHARMACIST_NUMBER,
            PrescriptionEntry.COLUMN_PRESCRIPTION_PHYSICIAN_NAME,
            PrescriptionEntry.COLUMN_PRESCRIPTION_PHYSICIAN_NUMBER};

    // This loader will execute the ContentProvider's query method on a background thread
    return new CursorLoader(this,   // Parent activity context
            PrescriptionEntry.CONTENT_URI,         // Query the content URI for the current store
            projection,             // Columns to include in the resulting Cursor
            null,                   // No selection clause
            null,                   // No selection arguments
            null);                  // Default sort order
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}



@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}



}
```

Comment: does your `onLoadFinished` gives valid data ?

Comment: If it was listview then I am sure it would give valid data but since I'm putting the swapcursor method in the recycleractivity I'm not sure that method is correct.

Comment: Use `data.getCount()` method inside `onLoadFinished` method to  check `Cursor` has some data.

Comment: Yes,it has data: I/MainTagName: Loader Manager Loading Finished: 2

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i got your problem. After getting new `Cursor` in `onLoadFinished` method you are calling `PrescriptionRecyclerAdapter`'s  `swapCursor()` method this method is updating `prescriptionCursor` Cursor reference. Thats OK. But updating  `prescriptionCursor` will not effect your `CursorAdapter`. You are actually dependent on `CursorAdapter`. So you have to update the`Cursor` of your `CursorAdapter`. Because your `mCursorAdapter` still holding the old reference of the `Cursor` you have provided in constructor.

So use this method to update Cursor reference `mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(prescriptionCursor)`.

```
public Cursor swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
  if (prescriptionCursor == cursor) {
    return null;
  }

  Cursor oldCursor = prescriptionCursor;
  this.prescriptionCursor = cursor;

  if (cursor != null) {
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    // update your Cursor for CursorAdapter
    mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(prescriptionCursor);
  }

  return oldCursor;
}
```

I think you have made it complex by maintaining two Adapter. You can use `RecyclerView.Adapter` with `List` or `Cursor`. There is not need to make it complex.

Hope it will help you. Let me know it solve your problem.